# How to add and remove class in JS?

Tags: javascript, class

I have been trying to make a simple exercise in JS. A box that changes the background color from white to blue or to purple but also from purple to blue etc in all directions. This is the code that is working BUT eg. I don't understand why the last blue: function() is also working. I have written everything by myself with "try and check method". Maybe someone can rewrite the code in the real correct way (the simplest way).

```
<style>
    #box {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 3px black solid;
    }
    .purple {
      background: purple;
    }
    .blue {
      background: blue;
    }
    .white {
      background: white;
    }
</style>

<div id="box"></div>
<div>
    <button onclick="colorChanger.white()">White </button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger.purple()">Purple </button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger.blue()">Blue </button>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
var background = document.getElementById("box");
var colorChanger = {
   white: function() {
    (background.classList.remove("blue") || background.classList.remove("purple")) 
   },
  purple: function() {
  (background.classList.remove("blue") || background.classList.remove("white")) & background.classList.add("purple");
  },
  blue: function() {
    background.classList.add("blue");
  }
};
```

Working script is here: https://codepen.io/hubkubas/pen/LJNKoJ?editors=1010

Thank You for Your help and advice.

Comment: The code never adds "white" to the class list. Also be careful with `&` vs `&&`; they're different.

Comment: because the "blue" class is the last one defined in the CSS, so it overrides the purple one when they're both defined together on the same element. Try swapping the position of the "purple" and "blue" entries in the CSS (so that purple is last) and see what happens. You never use the "white" class - if your overall page background wasn't white to begin with then neither would your box be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make this a whole lot simpler.

Simple, effective. You effectively overwrite the old class with the `newClass`. A mayor benefit of this method: If you have a lot of colors, you dont need a lot of functions.
<sub>*Note: If you have a class on the element you want to keep, you could  use `data-styling` and set that in your JS/CSS*</sub>

```js
var background = document.getElementById("box");

var colorChanger = {
  changeTo: function(newClass) {
    background.className = newClass;
  }
};
```

```css
#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px black solid;
  transition: all 0.5s; /* just for fun */
}
.purple {
  background: purple;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.white {
  background: white;
}
.goldWithSomePrettyGlow {
  background-color: gold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<div>
    <button onclick="colorChanger.changeTo('purple')">purple </button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger.changeTo('blue')">blue </button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger.changeTo('white')">White </button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger.changeTo('goldWithSomePrettyGlow')">goldWithSomePrettyGlow </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Martin - Keeping it simple helps mate! I have made a reference to your answer, I hope it is okay with you.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal  Please note this will of course destroy any other classes you might have on this,.  For something like this though, a data attribute is way better.

Comment: @Keith - Agreed and that is why specified the same in the answer.

Comment: No, not a problem (though my name contains a J ;) ). @Keith: I've added the data-* variant to my answer. The logic remains, but it was worth the note

Answer (score 4):

Your code with `blue` class worked because, in your code `white` class was never added. And whenever `blue` class was added irrespective of `purple` class being there or not, it had higher precedence because of which `blue` class worked.

Also, you can simply your code as follows

```js
function colorChanger(color) {
  var background = document.getElementById("box");
  background.className  = ""; // Remove all color classes
  background.classList.add(color); // Add clicked color class
}
```

```css
#box {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 3px black solid;
    }
    .purple {
      background: purple;
    }
    .blue {
      background: blue;
    }
    .white {
      background: white;
    }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="colorChanger('white')">White </button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger('purple')">Purple </button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger('blue')">Blue </button>
  </div>
```

Please Note, I would recommend [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078455/1132354) for further simplification of code i.e.

Updating from

```
  background.className = ""; // Remove all color classes
  background.classList.add(color); // Add clicked color class
```

to

```
background.className = color;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add jQuery library to make it simple. Below is a demo -

```js
var colorChanger = function (color) {
  $('#box').removeClass().addClass(color);
};
```

```css
#box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px black solid;
  }

.purple {
  background: purple;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.white {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="box"></div>
  
  <div>
    <button onclick="colorChanger('white')">White </button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger('purple')">Purple </button>
    <button onclick="colorChanger('blue')">Blue </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: jQuery is not a requirement for this question

Comment: Nor is it needed to make it simple :) Todays javascripts class options are more than adequate for the job.

Answer (score 0):

For me, a class is not really the best option for this.

Data attributes make more sense, also style based on ID doesn't hold well with me either, so I've used a classname called `nice-box` instead, and this makes using the data-attribute make even more sense, because if you just cleared the class, it would break the styling.

Below is an example.

```js
var background = document.getElementById("box");

function toggle(color) {
  background.dataset.boxColor = color;
}

var colorChanger = {
  white: function() { toggle("white"); },
  purple: function() { toggle("purple"); },
  blue: function() { toggle("blue"); }
};
```

```css
[data-box-color=purple] {
  background: purple;
}
[data-box-color=blue] {
  background: blue;
}
[data-box-color=white] {
  background: white;
}
.nice-box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="nice-box"></div>
<div>
  <button onclick="colorChanger.white()">White </button>
  <button onclick="colorChanger.purple()">Purple </button>
  <button onclick="colorChanger.blue()">Blue </button>
</div>
```